# Android Firebase get ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to ask about how to get the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP using viewholder and convert it to display into textView.
here are my codes in my database "Rating"

```
ratingDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rating").push();
            Map userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("comment", comments);
            userMap.put("foodId", foodId);
            userMap.put("rateValue", String.valueOf(value));
            userMap.put("userName", firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            userMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            ratingDatabase.setValue(userMap);
```

I tried to get any data on the Rating but it will always be null in return. how can I get inside the "Rating" directory with "Push key"? do I just need to database.child("Rating") or database.child("Rating").push? I know that push key will give a generated key and I just want to get the child inside the directory.

this is my code for getting the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

```
 if (getIntent()!=null)
            {
                foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.INTENT_SHOW_COMMENT);
                if (!foodId.isEmpty() &&  foodId !=null)
                {
                    Query query = ratingTbl.orderByChild("foodId").equalTo(foodId);
                    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Rating> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Rating>().setQuery
                            (query, Rating.class).build();

                    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Rating, ShowCommentViewholder>(options) {
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ShowCommentViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Rating model) {
                            //String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                            holder.Ratingbar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(model.getRateValue()));
                            holder.TxtEmail.setText(model.getUserName());
                            holder.TxtComment.setText(model.getComment());
                           /* ratingDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rating").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String time = dataSnapshot.child("comment").getValue().toString();
                                    GetTime getTimeAgo = new GetTime();
                                    long lastime = Long.parseLong(time);
                                    String LastComment= getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastime, ViewComment.this);
                                    holder.Date.setText(time);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });*/

                        }
```

and Here is my Rating Model Class

```
public class Rating {
private String userName, foodId, rateValue, comment;
private long timestamp;


public Rating() {
}

public Rating(String userName, String foodId, String rateValue, String comment) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.foodId = foodId;
    this.rateValue = rateValue;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;

}

public long getTime() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.timestamp = time;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getFoodId() {
    return foodId;
}

public void setFoodId(String foodId) {
    this.foodId = foodId;
}

public String getRateValue() {
    return rateValue;
}

public void setRateValue(String rateValue) {
    this.rateValue = rateValue;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}


}
```

and my ViewHolder

```
public ShowCommentViewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    TxtComment = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowComment);
    TxtEmail = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.useremail);
    Ratingbar =  (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RatingResult);
    Date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);


  }
}
```

Hoping that Someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ServerValue.TIMESTAMP using viewholder and convert it to display into textView.

ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is **time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds** determined by the Firebase servers. To convert into date you need to use -

```
SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String date = sfd.format(new Date(timestamp)) //timestamp is model.getTime() in your case
```

> how can I get inside the "Rating" directory with "Push key"?

**No.** In order to just access the data, Browse through `.child()`, `push()` is used to insert data to node with unique key.

Comment: How can i view it using textview? Do i just need to use model.getcomment()? Sorry but i’m just confused. I tried To get it directly to node by i always encounter null object. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Wait, what's coming `null`?

Comment: When i tried to get the getValue on my database. I used ratingdatabase.child(“Rating”) and i can’t get any value but on my other database is okay

Comment: Okay, then may be something wrong with process of fetching data.

Comment: So it look like this Right? Model.getTime(timestamp);?

Comment: Just make sure your query is good, There is data in model, `model.getTime()` does not returns `null`. then you will be able to convert timestamp into date and set it to the `TextView`

Comment: I Successfully conver it using GetTimeAgo but when i try to comment,  all of the data result will be just now, every time i get just now. here is my code.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gathb6  

on the code looks like it's converting the latest data so when i run the app it will always show just now when there is a now data

Comment: Okay, I don't know what *GetTime* class is.. but there might be `timeZone ` problem. Try to set Timezone to **UTC** because Firebase will return time in **UTC** format

Comment: I get it here on stackoverflaw and tried it. So maybe the problem is not on the datachange? I’ll try that maybe tomorrow, thankyou for the reply by the way appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, There is  a way to appreciate ;) +1